# gRPC and Swagger annotation differences

Tags: go, swagger, protocol-buffers, grpc-gateway

I have a protocol buffer definition, which includes `google.protobuf.Timestamp` as part of a message. The Timestamp message is pretty simple and has the following definition:

```proto
message Timestamp {
  int64 seconds = 1;
  int32 nanos = 2;
}
```

So the gRPC payload comes out as a simple tuple of values as expected. However I also wanted to generate some swagger annotations for REST API for the same message, but it seems to convert the Timestamp into an RFC 3339 style string:

```json
"timestamp": {
  "type": "string",
  "format": "date-time",
  "title": "timestamp"
}
```

I recently started working with protocol buffers and gRPC, so I am not sure if I am missing something here, but it seems to be an inconsistency with grpc-gateway implementation. Why would REST be a different format than the gRPC payload? Or am I missing some way to tell protoc-gen-swagger not to convert the message into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that familiar with protoc-gen-swagger itself, but I believe this is happening because of the json-proto format defined here:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json

It's done this way to make it more "natural" for JSON-based APIs. 
I don't know of any way to avoid this except by using your own type to hold the timestamp instead of `google.protobuf.Timestamp`.  However, JSON conversion is expected to work correctly in both directions, so when the JSON is converted back to a proto message by the library, it should not cause any problems.

Comment: Hey @DougFawley, you are right, that seems to be the way it is. Code in protoc-gen-swagger literally checks for "google.protobuf.Timestamp" type and builds a string. It's great to have a consistent rfc3339-type string, but from the code efficiency point of view, it's a conversion of a string back and forth from secs/nanosecs format. But again, what am I talking about when discussing REST and json payload anyways - everything is a string! our sdk on the other side is C++, so the conversion back is not as straightforward, so I ended up defining my own "Timestamp" message and that helped.